# What difficulties occur in a three sided version of Space Hulk?

Tags: house-rules, space-hulk

The Space Hulk Campaigns book outlines Marine vs Marine rules. Is it possible to then play Terminators vs Chaos Terminators vs Genestealers or are there game mechanics that make this unworkable e.g. Overwatch over two turns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**

- Three sided play should be entirely possible, and sounds fun!
- The game mechanics should not be affected to any great degree.
- I see the game progressing for each individual action as though the game is only a one on one.
- Players would need to simply keep the bigger picture in mind as the game progresses.
- Whether there is two or three players one full turn still ends when the same player starts his turn again.
- You may want to develop house rules for the total number of AP in a turn, to avoid bottle-necking?

I have only ever played the tabletop version a couple times; but I have played the steam version quite a few, though it has been a few years. Personally, I foresee no issues playing a three sided match in this game. Simply progress the turns as you would normally. When you take an action against another player the game would progress as though it was simply a one on one; strategically you would just have to pay attention to where the other third player is.

In my mind I see Marine -> Genestealer -> Chaos for a turn order. As this would play out I see the Terminator entering overwatch at the end of his turn. The game would of course progress as normal for the Genestealer turn. Then on the Chaos turn the Terminator would remain in Overwatch and the game would essentially progress as if it were only Marine vs. Chaos for that turn. Then when the Marine starts his new turn the game progresses as normal.

Looking at the broad picture each player would look at the game as "me vs. whoever's turn it is" and on their turn they would look at it one action at a time as "me vs. whoever I want to attack this with this action."

The only trip up that might come into play that I can think of is the number of free actions/ actions points/ command points that you have. I feel like you might want to have some house rules in this case. If you only have the standard maximum number of actions in a turn it is possible that the game will not progress quickly enough (kill off opponents) and all three players will bottleneck in one area limiting everyone's choices?

Perhaps I have forgotten something that would come into play and hinder this progression. If so let me know... otherwise I hope this helps.

Comment: I meant to put Traitor Marines as opposed to Chaos but it's moot now. Thinking about it, ovewatch and other effects must last two turns, otherwise one marine player would lose out. Would an Assault Cannon on Ovewatch (or any ammo limited weapon?) for the Chaos Marine be disadvantaged here as the Terminator is harder to kill than a Genestealer, so would use more ammo up the turn after they set Overwatch?

Comment: That was exactly my though as well. And regarding weapons, maybe. That is another aspect that you might need to develop some house rules to make it fair. The first time you play I would kind of make it a test game and start exactly as the rules describe. Then once you reach a situation where you see the rules fail or at least heading in that direction, come up with a community adjustment to try and fix it. Then keep playing with that rule in place. The hardest part should be just ensuring that one faction does not have an edge over everyone else and everyone has a chance to win.